# Is it possible to call Silverlight code behind methods through an ASPX Page?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, methods, silverlight-5.0

I have embedded a Silverlight application in my ASP.NET page and this Silverlight       application has two methods.

I want to call those methods through the ASPX page, i.e. my ASPX page has one `Button` control and when I click this button I want to call one of the Silverlight methods.

Is it possible? How would I do it?

Comment: No idea how this could ever work as Silverlight is on the client.  You are trying to get a aspx code behind event to call a client based Silverlight method.  Sounds like you need to have a good look at your requirements.

Comment: Depending on what you want, you might be able to do it using the Javascript/Silverlight "bridge".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Javascript to make a silverlight method calls.

To permit user to access method of Silverlight from JavaScript, you have to set [ScriptableMember] attribute to that method.

If you want to invoke those methods by ASPX methods/events, you should generate Javascript that invokes the silverlight methods.

Example:

**Silverlight:**

**ScriptableClass.cs**

```
public class ScriptableClass
    {
        [ScriptableMember]
        public void ShowAlertPopup(string message)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message, "JS Message", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
 private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
            ScriptableClass myScript = new ScriptableClass();
            HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("scriptableClass", myScript);
        }
```

**index.html**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">     
        var ctlSLHost = null;
        function onPluginLoaded(sender, args) {
            ctlSLHost = sender.getHost();
        }

        function InvokeSLMethod_ShowAlertPopup() {
            ctlSLHost.Content.scriptableClass.ShowAlertPopup
        ("Showing alert from JS in SL!");
        } 
    </script>

<div>
        <div style="width: 250px; background: lightblue; font-weight: bold;height:30px">
            HTML Part
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Invoke SL Method - ShowAlertPopup" 
        onclick="InvokeSLMethod_ShowAlertPopup();" /></div>
    </div>

 <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
            width="100%" height="80%">
            <param name="source" value="ClientBin/Silverlight2JSViseVersa.xap" />
            <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
            <param name="background" value="white" />
            <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
            <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />         
            <param name="onLoad" value="onPluginLoaded" />

            <a href=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0 
        style="text-decoration: none">
                <img src=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376 
        alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                    style="border-style: none" />
            </a>
        </object>
```